# (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches() is not working properly

Tags: java, android

I want to check whether a page exists or not. I used the following code:

```
 url = "https://muslimmemo.com/page/" + ++page;

            if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches())
            {
                Log.d("response","the url exists. page is " + page);
                Title title = new Title(getApplicationContext());
                title.execute();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("response","the url does not exist.");
            }
```

In above code, the if condition is always true, in spite of the fact that `https://muslimmemo.com/page/7` does not exist. The page increases and never stops. How can I solve this?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the `matches()` method. It's only detect that the `url` is in valid format. It's can't detect as if the `url` is exist or not.

Comment: Is it the case? How fool am I? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

> Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches()

Checks only if url has valid syntax, i.e url like: `000:/some.url` will be not valid.

If you want to check if url exists on server, you can send a simple GET request, like this:

```
public boolean exists(String url){
    HttpURLConnection huc =  ( HttpURLConnection )  url.openConnection (); 
    huc.setRequestMethod ("GET");  //OR  huc.setRequestMethod ("HEAD"); 
    huc.connect () ; 
    int code = huc.getResponseCode() ;

    if(code==200)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
}
```

P.S Don't forget to send it in background thread as any other network operation.